# Regarding pattern of Salesforce DEV- 401 certification exam

Tags: certification

I have recently given Salesforce Dev-401 certification exam. But I failed. 
I just wanted to know does any one over here has a idea that why Salesforce don't provide complete result with right and wrong questions count and correct answers for wrong once?
And if no one knows answer of this question then has someone tried to post this idea into "Salesforce IDEA" or any one has raised this question via "Salesforce CASE"? if any one did that then what was the reply?
Please answer to this question as soon as possible, so that I'll raise this case or I'll post this idea, if no one has did it before.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In my opinion (!) the exames are not about learning some content, but gaining experience with the platform, its functionality and business processes in general. In that context it may be considered good that you're not receiving black-and-white results, as not passing and exam shouldn't be interpreted as a "need to more study", but as a general need for more experience.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rahu, you should be able to check the Salesforce Ideas yourself, certainly you can register for a development org so that you can get a salesforce username and then log into success.salesforce.com and search for the answer to your question there or alternatively post your question there. Let me know if you need more detail on what to do. Salesforce don't give answer results per question as it would then be easier to hack the exam.

Answer (score 2):

I would imagine that there is a limited pool of questions from which the exam is drawn, and that by providing complete results would make it easier to game the system.

Still I agree it would be nice to know your score and whether it's a close pass or fail, etc. It could also help to identify areas of strength and weakness.

When you do the advanced (DEV501) there is individual feedback provided for the assignment.